# Populating dropdown list from comma seperated values in textbox ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu, textbox, datasource, populate

I want to populate a dropdownlist with comma seperated values from a textbox. I have below code:

```
sDDvalues = txtValues.Text

Me.DropDownList1.Items.Clear()
Dim months() As String = {sDDvalues}
Me.DropDownList1.DataSource = months
Me.DropDownList1.DataBind()
```

I have entered in the textbox like: value1, value2 and "value1", "value2" and 'value1','value2', but every combination is returned as 1 option:

```
<option value="'value1', 'value2'">'value1', 'value2'</option>
```

Entering the actual values for months() like: {"value1", "value2"} returns a correct dropdown:

```
<option value="value1">value1</option>
<option value="value2">value2</option>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this, so it populates from the values in the textbox?

Thanks in advance!

Marcellino

Comment: Rephrase your question please.

Comment: Dont forget to updvote and mark answer as accepted if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
Me.DropDownList1.DataSource = txtValues.Text.Split(New Char() {" "c, "-"c})
```

So completed:

```
Me.DropDownList1.Items.Clear()
Me.DropDownList1.DataSource = txtValues.Text.Split(New Char() {" "c, "-"c})
Me.DropDownList1.DataBind()
```

Input in the textbox would be like: `value1 value2 value3`

If you wanted to have it split at a comma then use:

```
Me.DropDownList1.DataSource = txtValues.Text.Split(",")
```

Input in the textbox would be like: this is my value1, this is my value2, this is my value3

Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Dim months() As String = txtValues.Text.Split(New Char() {", "c})
Me.DropDownList1.DataSource = months
```

Comment: why to create extra variable Dim months() As String ...why dont assinged directly

Comment: @ Pranay Rana: Can You explain why should You assign directly?

Answer (score 0):

just split string and write this will do work for you

```
Me.DropDownList1.DataSource = txtValues.Text.Split(New Char() {", "c})
```

Comment: Thanks! But this returns below error:

    BC30456: 'Split' is not a member of 'System.Array'.

Comment: Ok, this retruns this error: BC30004: Character constant must contain exactly one character.